# MongoDB large array in document performance

Tags: mongodb

I want to build an app using MongoDB Atlas that has users, and each user has many transactions (from 1 thousand to 1 million transactions per user, or even more in the worst case) and I don't know how to organize my database.

99% of the time, a user will get only his own transactions (and not from other users, because these are private in most cases).

Users can upload from 1 to 1000 (or even more) transactions per day.

Every transaction contains 10 to 15 simple fields.

I found this doc https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/schema-suggestions/avoid-unbounded-arrays/ which says that in this case I should make a new collection for all the transactions and that I should use $lookup. But in that collection then I would have millions and millions of transactions from every user.
In the same doc it says "$lookup operations are not very performant".

So what should I do?

1_ This for every user:

```
 {
    _id: 1,
     transactions: [{_id: 1, ...}, {_id: 2, ...}, ..., {_id: 1000000, ... ]
 }
```

2_ Should I make another collection for the transactions, and every transaction would look like this:

```
 {
    _id: 1,
    userId: _1,
    ...
 }
```

3_ ??????

Answer (score 0):

As the link you referenced is suggesting, you should avoid using unbounded arrays in these situations. There are not many solutions in this specific case, so the second approach you were suggesting looks good to me. It's true that lookups are not really performant, but that's the best you can do with MongoDB.

However, if you are concerned about performances, maybe you should look to another DB technology. In this specific case, a graph-based database fits really well. Have a look to [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/) for instance, it's fast and really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it.